# node.js process.hrtime in asynchronous server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I create a http server using `http.createServer(onRequest)` and want to measure time needed to make a response.

Currently, in my `onRequest` handler I do:

```
var start = process.hrtime();

response.on('end', function (){
    console.log('time to respond', process.hrtime(start));
});

// call various asynchronous functions and send them 'response' object. One of them eventually does response.end()
```

I'm worried if this will work fine when a bunch of requests comes instantly, or will asynchronism break it/mix-up times?

Answer (score 2):

You should do somethinng like,

```
function measureRequestTime (req, res, next) {
  var start = process.hrtime();
  response.on('end', function () {
    // logging the time here..
  });
}

// app init

app.use(meastureTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable will be in the closure scope of your `onRequest` handler function so it'll work just the way you expect it to (assuming `process.hrtime` does what you want).